# WebAPI - XMLInput Remove need to specify Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, webapi

On the interwebs I am able to find out how to remove the namespace declaration on the OUTPUT of xml files, but I want to remove the dependency on the INPUT of xml files;

so instead of having to input this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AcquisitionDetails xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServicesTools.WebServices">
  <Acquisition>
    <GeoCode>PHX</GeoCode>
    <OrderDate>3/9/2020 12:00:00 AM</OrderDate>
  </Acquisition>
<AcquisitionDetails>
```

I just want to input this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AcquisitionDetails>
  <Acquisition>
    <GeoCode>PHX</GeoCode>
    <OrderDate>3/9/2020 12:00:00 AM</OrderDate>
  </Acquisition>
<AcquisitionDetails>
```

Reason being that I am unable to control the xml that I will receive, and the customer is unwilling/unable to modify it for my purpose alone, stating that this works with other suppliers as well.; so I would assume they figured out a way to do it..

I am using this in my ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

and this is the Model definition

```
    [CollectionDataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServicesTools.WebServices")]
    public class AcquisitionDetails : List<Acquisition>
    {


    }


    [DataContract(Name = "Acquisition", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServicesTools.WebServices")]
    public class Acquisition
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "GeoCode",Order =1)]
        public string GeoCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "OrderDate", Order =2)]
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Supplier", Order =6)]
        public string Supplier { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PartNo", Order =3)]
        public string PartNo { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "QtyExpected", Order =4)]
        public int QtyExpected { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PONumber", Order =5)]
        public Int64 PONumber { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Can't you just replace `Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServicesTools.WebServices"` with `Namespace = ""` from your `DataContract` attributes?

Comment: I tried, but when I offer the XML using postmen, I get a BadRequest anyway

Comment: it did work after I went to .net framework instead of .net core; so it seems there is a difference in implementation there?

Comment: There are definitely differences in how asp.net and asp.net-core are initialized and configured, possibly e.g. causing a different serializer to be chosen.  But once a serializer is chosen, at the low level `DataContractSerializer` (and `XmlSerializer`) should work pretty much the same.  So hard to say why one worked and the other did not.

Comment: BTW, you might re-tag your question with the tags for the framework(s) and technologies you are using, e.g. [tag:asp.net-core] or [tag:asp.net-web-api] or [tag:DataContractSerializer].  The tag [tag:webapi] is for *Questions related to web browser's Web APIs specification* and so doesn't apply here.